# Is there a modern version of "Deep Zoom Composer" for Silverlight that allows for stitching together panoramic images?

Tags: c#, html, xamarin, panoramas, deepzoom

Silverlight used to offer ["deep zoom"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409068.aspx), a technology that respected bandwidth as the user zoomed in and out.

Finally, after many years I found a use for it; [using images from a hot air ballon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=damWIvQn1Eo) for students to see the effects of climate change on a micro, and macro level.

**Q**
How can I make panoramic photos "zoomable", similar to Deep Zoom in Silverlight?

Comment: I would look at the various "mapping" tile-based APIs that are available as they offer pan and "smooth" zoom (this is basically what Deepzoom did, and now Google Maps, Bing Maps, etc... does). There are a bunch of OSS  tile caching servers, API and mobile libraries (and html/javascript) for interfacing to those services/services if you do not what to roll your own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://openseadragon.github.io/ is the JavaScript cousin of Deep Zoom (both came from the same team within Microsoft, though OpenSeadragon is independent now). It does the client side viewing, and uses the same DZI format that Deep Zoom used.

For the DZI creation, you can continue using whatever tool you're already using and just view it with OpenSeadragon. Here's a list of additional conversion tools:

http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/creating-zooming-images/